# How do I disable a hyperlink when value from db is 0 for a particular row?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We have a bunch of records on the db.

Some have zero (0) values.

Then on the markup, we have the following link:

`<asp:HyperLink ID="hypG773" runat="server" Text="Get It" navigateurl='<%# String.Format("gets.aspx") %>' Target="_blank"   />`

We would like to disable the hyperlink above if the value of a particular record is 0.

The code below:

```
Protected Sub DataList1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataListItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        Dim sid As Integer
        Dim dr As DataRowView = TryCast(e.Item.DataItem, DataRowView)
        sid = dr("sid")

        If sid = "0" Then
            Dim lnkbtn As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("hypG773"), HyperLink)
            lnkbtn.Enabled = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

gives me the following error:

**Input string was not in a correct format.**

The error points to this line below:

**Line 38:            sid = dr("sid")**

I think it has to do with data type.

Sid is of integer data type.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In debug mode when you look at `dr("sid")` what value does it have?

Comment: not familiar with vb.net, but you declare sid as integer, and then compare it to the string "0". That seems quite odd to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid doing the codebehind stuff if you do it this way:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>'>HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

Sample class:

```
Public Class MyLinks
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Property Enabled As Integer
End Class
```

and bind my `DataList` like this:

```
Dim myLinksList As New List(Of MyLinks)
myLinksList.Add(New MyLinks With {.Enabled = 1, .Url = "http://www.google.com"})
myLinksList.Add(New MyLinks With {.Enabled = 0, .Url = "http://www.google.com"})
myLinksList.Add(New MyLinks With {.Enabled = 1, .Url = "http://www.google.com"})
myLinksList.Add(New MyLinks With {.Enabled = 1, .Url = "http://www.google.com"})
myLinksList.Add(New MyLinks With {.Enabled = 0, .Url = "http://www.google.com"})

Me.DataList1.DataSource = myLinksList
Me.DataList1.DataBind()
```

When you bind the sid field to the `Enabled` property, it should work.

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("sid") %>'
```

**EDIT**

---

You could also do the following (as part of a different solution):

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypG773" runat="server" Text="Get It" navigateurl='<%# String.Format("gets.aspx") %>' Enabled='<%# getEnabled(Eval("sid")) %>' Target="_blank" />
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
Public Function getEnabled(ByVal sid As Object) As Boolean
    Return Convert.ToInt32(sid)
End Function
```

Comment: @gtr1971, I did remove the quotes. same error.

Hanlet, thanks for the code but it confused the heck out of me. I copied it as is but got a bunch of errors that myLinksList is not declared even though I copied `public class MyLinks` first.

Also, the hyperlink code I posted has some parameters for gets.aspx like:

`<%# String.Format("gets.aspx?id={0}&pos={1}", Eval("Id"), Eval("posters")) %>'`

Comment: You should not try the same code. As I mentioned, I have a sample class. Maybe try using the second solution.

Comment: Still getting same error: `input string not in correct format`.

Comment: It is working fine now with the following code, a slight mod from yours:

    `Public Function getEnabled(ByVal sid As Object) As Boolean
        Return Int32.TryParse(sid, 0)
    End Function`

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit foggy on how data types are expressed in .NET, but make sure the declared dataype of Integer is consistent with how it is in the DB. You might have to either convert a string, or change the datatype to a Long.

Also, the `If sid = "0"` part might be implying that it's a string and not a digit, so maybe removing the quotes would fix it.